# Java Null Pointer Exception with array of ArrayList

Tags: java

I have found many related post here but couldn't get my answer.Why this run-time error ?

```
static List<Integer>[] adj = (List<Integer>[]) new ArrayList[1000];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int edge, u, v, source;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        edge = input.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < edge; i++) {
            u = input.nextInt();
            v = input.nextInt();
            adj[v].add(u); // Null pointer Exception
            adj[u].add(v); // Null pointer Exception
        }
```

Comment: Just because you create the array, it doesn't mean each entry (each `ArrayList`) is being created. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to initialize each elements of your array. Because until you do this, your reference in the array are not pointing to any object.

So, before that for-loop, you can add this one, to initialize your `List` inside the `Array`: -

```
for (List<Integer> elem: adj) {
    elem = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

Also, it would be better if you have `List of List` rather than an `array of List`. So, you can declare your list as: -

```
static List<List<Integer>> adj = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

An advantage of using an `ArrayList` is that, you don't have to limit your size at the beginning. So, you can add any number of elements. But, if it is a requirement to create a fixed size list, you can pass the size parameter in your `ArrayList` constructor.

And then you need to change your element adding code from: -

```
adj[v].add(u);
```

to: -

```
adj.get(v).add(u);
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting using a list of list. I think that would be the way to go.

Comment: @Sujay. Yeah using list of list is always a better option than a 2-D array or an array of list. :)

Comment: okay, using `static List<List<Integer>> adj = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(100);
` is a nice idea.I tried to use it before but can't figure out the `adj[u].add(v);` portion. What will be this code then?

Comment: Just some pedantry: you mean 'initialize', not 'instantiate' in your first sentence. To 'initialize' something is to assign a value to it, when it has not yet had one assigned. To 'instantiate' something (generally a class) means to create an instance of it. Incidentally, we're instantiating ArrayList objects here to populate the array with, but we're still initializing the array elements, not instantiating them. May I suggest you edit your answer?

Comment: `IndexOutOfBoundsException` on the line `adj.get(u).add(v);` :(

Comment: @user1658353. Then that is some other problem. You are trying to access outof index list. Better option would be, not to fix the size of list.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you don't allocate `adj[v]`. You can't call the `add` method on `null`.

You could do

```
   for (int i = 0; i < edge; i++) {
        u = input.nextInt();
        v = input.nextInt();
        if (adj[v]==null) adj[v] = new ArrayList();
        adj[v].add(u); 
        if (adj[u]==null) adj[u] = new ArrayList();
        adj[u].add(v); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created an array for sure but you've not allocated each element of the array. As such when you're trying to add to the *non-existant* elements, you experience a NullPointerException.

As a side-note, what you're trying to achieve would look a lot better if you create a List of List. In other words:

```
List<List<Integer>> yourList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

You can then initialize each of your individual list inside *yourList* and then put elements into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer>[] adj = (List<Integer>[]) new ArrayList[1000];
```

says `adj` is a reference to 1000 `ArrayList` references. You need to initialize each of those `ArrayList`s as well.

```
private final int MAX = 1000;
static List<Integer>[] adj = (List<Integer>[]) new ArrayList[MAX];
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
       adj[i] = new ArrayList();
    }

    int edge, u, v, source;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    edge = input.nextInt();


    for (int i = 0; i < edge; i++) {
        u = input.nextInt();
        v = input.nextInt();
        adj[v].add(u); // Null pointer Exception
        adj[u].add(v); // Null pointer Exception
    }
```